# Why do I get ValidationError on my serializer when I shouldn't be getting one?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So I have this serializer:

```py
class MarkReadDeserializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Message.objects.all())
    is_read = serializers.BooleanField()
```

And view:

```py
class MarkReadView(CreateAPIView):
    read_serializer_class = MarkReadSerializer
    write_serializer_class = MarkReadDeserializer

    def get_write_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['many'] = True
        return super().get_write_serializer(args, kwargs)
```

Now my view is being POSTed data in the shape of:

```js
[{"id": 1, "is_read": true}, {"id": 2, "is_read": false}]
```

When this happens I get this error:

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'is_read': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

I did override my `is_valid` method in serializer to see the initial data:

```py
    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        print(self.initial_data)
```

And it is printing expected:

```py
{'data': [{'id': 123, 'is_read': True}, {'id': 122, 'is_read': True}, {'id': 121, 'is_read': True}, {'id': 120, 'is_read': True}], 'many': True}
```

Why do I get the `ValidationError`?

Comment: I can see that your *posted* data and the initial_data are different.

Comment: show your view class method